# <br> not being appended to div

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

```
ogres = document.getElementById('${contentID}')
```

.

```
let prettify = streamArray[streamArray.length - 1].split(/--/),
                                    layers = document.createTextNode(prettify[0]),
                                    onions = document.createTextNode(prettify[1]),
                                    breaking = document.createElement('br');
```

I have an array of two elements that I've created called `prettify`.

I have definitely confirmed that the `prettify[0]` and `prettify[1]` are the elements I want so I make them into `onions` and `layers` which are text nodes to be appended to the div.

You'll note I also have `breaking` which is a break element I create and also append to the div.

I then have the div, `orges`.

Now for some unknown reason when I do this:

```
ogres.appendChild(layers);
ogres.appendChild(breaking);
ogres.appendChild(onions);
ogres.appendChild(breaking);
```

on the html page, this is created:

```
layersonions
<br>
```

1: why is this happening

2: how do I fix it?

3: no I don't plan on keeping these variable names, but they are fun :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `document.createElement('br');` to create an element, it is appended as the second node of the parent.

Since you are using the same reference again, it simply detaches the existing element and appends it again in the new position.

It is a single reference to the element. To fix it you will have to create and append an element on the fly.

```
ogres.appendChild(layers);
ogres.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
ogres.appendChild(onions);
ogres.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

**[appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)**

If you still want to use the variable reference then you could use the `cloneNode` method which will clone the existing node before insertion.

```
ogres.appendChild(layers);
ogres.appendChild(breaking);
ogres.appendChild(onions);
ogres.appendChild(breaking.cloneNode(false));
```

**[cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)**

Comment: Works! Mucho Gracias you have my upvote and correct answer thingy!